# Dimple.js doesn't like my Array

Tags: javascript, dimple.js

I have data.json in this format:

```
{
    "Users": [
        {
            "userName": "Herbie",
            "weigh-in data": [
                { "date": "2016.01.04", "weight": "114.3" },
                { "date": "2016.01.05", "weight": "114.6" },
                { "date": "2016.01.06", "weight": "114.9" }
            ]
        },
        {
            "userName": "Wayne",
            "weigh-in data": [
                { "date": "2016.02.01", "weight": "120.3" },
                { "date": "2016.02.05", "weight": "123.6" },
                { "date": "2016.02.06", "weight": "123.9" }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

// etc., more user objects

In my application: a selection of a user is made, an ajax call gets this data, I loop thru it to get only the selected user's weigh-in data, and I'm successfully rendering this data to a table.

Now I'm trying to use the same result in a Dimple chart but Dimple evidently doesn't like my chartData array:

```
var dataObj = JSON.parse(jsonData);
var usersArray = dataObj.Users;
var chartData = [];
// etc. SNIP

for (var obj of usersArray) {
    if (obj.userName === selUser) { // weigh-ins of the selected user only
        dataRows.innerHTML = "";
        for (var i = 0, j = selUserData.length; i < j; i++) {
            var dataDate = selUserData[i].date;
            var dataWeight = selUserData[i].weight;

            chartData.push('{ "User"' + ': ' + '"'+selUser+'", ' + '"Date":' + ' ' + '"'+dataDate+'", ' + '"Weight":' + ' ' + '"'+dataWeight+'" }');

            // SNIP: build rows from the data, load up the table, no problem
            dataRows.innerHTML += row;
        } // selUserData loop

var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 800, 600);
var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, chartData);
chart.setBounds(60, 30, 505, 305);
var x = chart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Date");
x.addOrderRule("Dates");
var y = chart.addCategoryAxis("y", "Weight");
y.addOrderRule("Weights");

var s = chart.addSeries("weigh-ins", dimple.plot.line);
chart.draw();
```

... which results in a non-chart. However, if I console.log or alert(chartData) and set the result as chartData, i.e.:

```
var chartData = [
    { "User": "Wayne", "Date": "2016.02.01", "Weight": "180.3" },
    { "User": "Wayne", "Date": "2016.02.05", "Weight": "123.6" },
    { "User": "Wayne", "Date": "2016.02.06", "Weight": "153.9" }
]
```

... then I get a chart, ergo my confusion.

Any insight greatly appreciated,

Whiskey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pushing the JSON into your array as strings not objects, it should be:

```
chartData.push({ "User": selUser, "Date": dataDate, "Weight": dataWeight });
```

Which has the added benefit of being much easier to read!

Comment: Ah, thanks so much John. I could have sworn that was one of the ways I built chartData array (and confirmed it was an array object) ... maybe not, or maybe I had another error then. Anyway, many thanks for your help and taking time to post; I now have a chart!